# Best ways to obtain splint kits?

Tags: kenshi

I haven't seen them in any shop and I only have found them in inventories of hired medics. Is there another way to buy/farm them aside from going down the research route?

Answer (score 1):

This question was possibly only a problem with earlier versions of Kenshi. In the version I am currently playing (.99), splint kits are pretty commonly sold by most vendor NPCs.